# How to determine attack roll

Tags: dnd-5e, attack-roll

I believe that you are supposed to add the strength modifier or dexterity modifier depending on if it is a melee weapon or if it is a ranged weapon respectively. Then add the proficiency bonus if they are proficient in the weapon. All of this is added to the roll of a d20. Am I correct?

Comment: Have you read the rules on attack rolls in the PHB or basic rules?

Answer (score 3):

### Proficiency

Your proficiency bonus is applied if you have proficiency with the weapon.  This is generally determined by your class.  Other factors may grant you proficiency with other weapons (e.g. High Elves have proficiency with longsword, shortsword, shortbow and longbow in addition to whatever weapons their class grants).

### Strength vs Dexterity

In general, melee weapons use Strength and ranged weapons use Dexterity.  Of course, there are exceptions (see *Weapon Properties* on PH p. 146-7.).

If the melee weapon is marked *finesse*, then you may use Dexterity *or* Strength (e.g. Rapier).

If the ranged weapon is marked *thrown* and may also be employed as a melee weapon, then you employ Strength rather than Dexterity (e.g. Spear).

If a ranged weapon is marked *thrown*, may be employed as a melee weapon, and is marked *finesse*, then you may employ Strength *or* Dexterity (e.g. Dagger).

Answer (score 1):

### Yes

You are correct - melee weapons use strength (even if thrown), ranged weapons use dexterity. On slight complication is that weapons with the Finesse characteristic use strength or dexterity at the users choice (usually whichever is better). If the person is proficient with the weapon they also add their proficiency bonus.

Comment: Thank you but I add proficiency  the attack roll also